# Align background image center, and adjusting up or down (vertically) relatively

Tags: html, css

I have a slider div, and a background image on it. Since the background image is not fit (too large), its centered:

http://jsfiddle.net/s5qvY/

```
<div id="slider"></div><hr><hr><img src="http://hdwallpaper2013.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Download-Flower-Background-Images-HD-Wallpaper.jpg" width="100%" />

#slider
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('http://hdwallpaper2013.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Download-Flower-Background-Images-HD-Wallpaper.jpg');
}
```

now I want to move the image up or down, relative to this centering. I saw here a kind of solution (sorry I could find):

`padding-top: 10px; margin-bottom: -10px;`

but that only works one direction, it can only push the image up. To move down like this is not possible (negative margins).

Any idea?

Comment: your `img` is outside the `div`...what are u trying to achieve??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `background-position` property (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp))

```
background-position: 50% 10%;
```

You can change the second value to align your background verticaly.

Answer (score 1):

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s5qvY/3/)

**CSS**

```
  html, body {
    width: 100%; /* important because slider id has width set in %ge*/
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat:none;
    background-image: url('http://hdwallpaper2013.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Download-Flower-Background-Images-HD-Wallpaper.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; /* browser support */
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;/* browser support */
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;/* browser support */
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: top center; /*you need this one*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background-position: center -50px;
```

Added to `#slider` should give you what you're after. Change `-50px` to any positive or negative value you desire.